# Git not pushing my sitemap on public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, sitemap, sitemap-generator-gem

I'm using ruby on rails `sitemap_generator` gem.

When I make new sitemap with `ruby sitemap.rb` command it displays this:

```
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                          11 links /  527 Bytes
Sitemap stats: 11 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m00s

Pinging with URL 'http://domain.com/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

But when I test my sitemap with google webmaster tools or other service it all displays I have only 3 links.

How can I fix it?

Here is my sitemap.rb file

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://domain.com"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  add '/about'
  add '/contact'
  # under services category
  add '/heyheyhey'
  add '/hey'
  add '/heyhey'
  add '/eur'
  add '/blog' , :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/blog/this-is-it'
  add '/blog/my-blog-post'
  add '/blog/crazy-blog'
end
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines
```

Comment: What are the actual contents of the `sitemap.xml.gz` file? Change the domain if you need to

Comment: just added to my question sitemap.rb @WesFoster

Comment: But when you access "domain.com/sitemap.xml.gz", what is the output?

Comment: 3 valid links (from tests). I don't know how to open .gz file.